# pigeonhole principle with sequence of numbers

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_{77})$ be positive numbers. Use the pigeonhole principle to show that, if $\sum_{i=1}^{77}{x_{i}} = 140$, then there exist $j$ and $k$ such that $\sum_{i=j}^{k}{x_{i}} = 13$.

Comment: What numbers? Positive integers?

Comment: yes. sorry.I edit the question..

Comment: Do you mean that there exist $i$ and $j$ such that $\sum_{k=i}^{j}{x_{k}} = 13$ or that there exist $a_{1},\ldots,a_{j}$ such that $x_{a_{1}}+\ldots+x_{a_{k}} = 13$?

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question. the "chosen" numbers are folowing in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=i}^{j}x_{k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{j}x_{k}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i-1}x_{k}$. In other word, you only need to care about the partial sum $s_{i}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i}x_{k}$.

Possible value of all $s_{i}$ and $s_{i}+13$ run from $1$ to $140+13=153$. No 2 partial sum have the same value. Assuming there is no 2 partial sum with a difference of $13$, then every partial sum with value $s_{i}$ will rule out 1 more possible value $s_{i}+13$ in the range from $1$ to $153$. Hence each $s_{i}$ would rule out a total of $2$ value.

There are $77$ possible partial sum. If each of them rule out $2$ possible value among $153$ possible value, then there would be contradiction since $77\times 2=154>153$.

Comment: There can be overlaps that rule out the same sums.  If there are sequences that sum to 11,37,63,99,125 we only rule out five others, not 10

Comment: @RossMillikan: no: 11 rule out 11 and 24; 37 rule out 37 and 50; 63 rule out 63 and 76; 99 rule out 99 and 112; 125 rule out 125 and 138. 5 other, but total is 10. We only rule out upward, so there is no overlap. Your comment would have applied if all 3 $s_{i}-13,s_{i},s_{i}+13$ are ruled out; which is why I only rule out $s_{i},s_{i}+13$ to avoid overlap issue.

Comment: @roi: each number is positive. In fact, the partial sums are strictly increasing.

Comment: oops.... I missunderstood the meaning....

Comment: thank you very much. but I didn't fully understand the final prove. I would say that if we rule out every s+13, we will have maximum 76 sums but there are 77 so 1 sum must be s+13 and we proved it..

Comment: Well it's essentially the same thing. Since you want to use pigeon hole, which I why I wrote that way.

Comment: I did use it . 77>75...